# Will asking for advice here affect a lawsuit?

Tags: legal

I plan to file a lawsuit against my company. If I describe the backstory and situation here and ask for advice, will it affect the lawsuit? I am yet to file it but I am meeting a lawyer this week

Comment: You are much better off asking the lawyer this question than us. Even if we were all trained lawyers here, it's impossible to answer your question without knowing a lot more about the situation, and it would be unwise to post that info before talking to your lawyer.

Comment: A question for Law.SE ?

Comment: Ask your lawyer. We cannot provide legal advice of this nature.

Comment: It may make sense to ensure you're posting anonymously, even if just asking this sort of question.

Comment: Hint: if you are planning on suing someone, it's probably not the best idea to announce this on a public forum using your real name (if that's actually your name)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I using a pen name. I will first consult with my lawyer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### We don't know.

Most folks here are not lawyers. And the ones who may be, are not here to offer professional services. Thus, it's likely that you may not get an objective answer.

You may however seek general advise without revealing much details/using anonymized information without revealing your or organization's identify.

**P. S.**: You may need to create a new Stack Exchange account which doesn’t reveal any personally identifiable details.

Comment: Additionally, it is impossible to know who here is an actual lawyer, and who just sounds good. Remember, "on the internet, nobody knows you're a dog."